# Return dated rows based on number of days ago

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am using `SQL Compact` and am currently trying to return a set of rows based on a datetime column. I would like to return only the rows that are **5 days old or more**.

My first thought was to do this:
`select * from table where datepart(month, dateCol) < datepart(month, getdate())`

The above statement is as far as my Sql-Ce knowledge will take me. Unfortunately the above example does not work too well once you get to the start of the month.

Any ideas on how to returns rows based on a specific number of days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where dateCol < dateadd(day, -5, getdate())
```

See [DATEADDD for SQL Server Compact](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174470.aspx)

Edit, after comment

```
select * from table where
         dateCol < dateadd(day, -(5+DATEPART(DAY, getdate())), getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) One more question - what if I wanted to change the query to return rows 5 days older than the start of the current month?